# Printing a const deque structure

Tags: c, printf, deque

I'm trying to print a double-ended queue (deque), which is also a const. My deque structure is simply:

```
struct node {
  int item;
  struct node *previous;
  struct node *next;
};

struct deque {
  struct node *start;
  struct node *end;
};
```

My take on this is as follows:

```
void deque_print(const struct deque *deq) {
  assert(deq);
  if (deq->start->item == deq->end->item) {
    printf("[%d]\n", deq->front->item);
  }
  else {
    printf("{");
    while (1) {
      printf("%d", deq->start->item);
      deq->start = deq->start->next; /// I know this is the problem
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("}\n");
  }
}
```

As noted in the code comments, I'm aware which line is causing the problem (since the type of deq is const). I would like to know how to improve this so that this can print. Please also don't change the function header/declaration.

Also, the function is printing all the elements, front to back. It is surrounded by curly brackets and each elements has a space between the next. So, if the elements front to back are 1,2,3,4,5 then the output should be:

```
{1 2 3 4 5}
```

Also, don't worry about the deque being empty, I know how to do that. I'm curious in the deque have at least 1 element.

---

In response to the first comment, I tried:

```
else {
    printf("{");
    struct llnode *temp = deq->start;
    while (1) {
      printf("%d", temp->item); /// problem
      temp = temp->next;
      if (temp == NULL) break;
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("}\n");
  }
```

and it still didn't work. My print function is giving me problems here

Comment: Just create a temporary `struct deque* temp = deq->start;` outside the loop and use that as `temp = temp->next;`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I also editing above so you can see what I did.

Comment: you should emphasize on **what** didn't work? Was there an error? Was there a segmentation fault? etc.

Comment: I believe it was a segmentation fault, but I fixed it. I used your suggest, but my conditional in the while loop was incorrect. So, I changed it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should save the deque length and use it in the while loop or you going to have a segFault, because `while(1)` iterates forever. Second i recommend you to use a temporal node as iterator, because once you print the deque you will lose the start node.

```
void deque_print(const struct deque *deq) {
  int i = 0;
  node *tmp_node = deq->start;
  printf("{");
  while (i < deq->length) { //assuming you have the variable in the struct
    printf("%d", tmp_node->item);
    tmp_node = tmp_node->next;
    printf(" ");
    i++;
  }
  printf("}\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the structure of deque or llnode. I would need to somehow keep updating it until I suppose a NULL is reached. I edited my question above to show another approach I tried.

Comment: but what problem is giving you? a segfault or the numbers in wrong order.

Comment: Actually, I realized I fixed it. My mistake in my updated edit was that I shouldn't check for when `temp == NULL` but rather when `temp->item == deq->end->item`. I appreciate the support regardless!

Comment: that not gonna work if you have the numer repeated in other node.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Thanks for that. I changed again to `if (temp == deq->end) break;`. Now, it seems to be working for repeated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
void deque_print(const struct deque *deq)
{
    if (deq == NULL)
    {
        printf("{}");
        return;
    }

    const struct node *node = deq->start;
    const struct node *end = deq->end;

    printf("{");
    while (node)
    {
        if (node == end)
        {
            printf("%d", node->item);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d ", node->item);
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("}");
}
```